# Today I triggered a "Human Verification" page when I failed to login with the correct credentials, am I going to get banned?

Tags: support, login, banning, captcha

Today I tried (and failed) to login with the correct info (I had skipped a some characters) and it showed me this page:

[image: Verify Page Image]

Where I had to tick a capcha box.

My questions is, could this result in a ban?

Comment: Since you are new to meta: possible downvotes to your question here would not impact your account or reputation.

Comment: Also, see [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/165483)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is common practice of many websites to show captchas if they have reason to assume that you are an automatic robot trying some default passwords to gain access to accounts you should not have access to. Then they test whether you are a robot. Typing a wrong password can trigger such a test.

There is no reason to be worried about this. Even if you get this a 100 times nothing will happen.

Comment: Failing a hundred times would be definitive proof that the user is actually human.